# Global variable linking behavior

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

i have two .c files `1.c` and `2.c` and a header file `3.h`

`1.c` has a global variable defined like this
`int table`

`2.c` has a global variable defined like this `extern int table` and
 includes 3.h

`3.h` has `int table` declared.

Does compiler allow this? If yes, How likely is `table` in `1.c` going to be corrupted(by 2.c)?

I hope i made myself clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File `1.c` declares a global variable `int table;`.

File `3.h`, once included in a source file, declares a global variable `int table;`. It is included in `2.c` so `2.c` now also has declared a global variable `int table;`.

They will compile fine, but you probably get a linker error saying that `table` is multiply defined.